# RavenDB Studio - Patch can't find this.__document_id

Tags: ravendb, ravendb-studio

I'm trying to write a patch over a Collection that involves getting the current document ID and I was trying to test it to see the output in the RavenDB Studio Patch area which does a good job of showing before and after. I couldn't understand why my script wasn't working the way I expect and I managed to narrow it down to this small piece:

```
this.TestId = this.__document_id
```

In the output for my document when running the test is:

```
TestId: null
```

But I can see the document Id is `users/1234`. Does anyone know the correct syntax to pull the document Id out in the JavaScript used by the RavenDB Studio?

RavenDB Version: #2230

Answer (score 6):

Remove the 'this' in front of the '__document_id'.

```
this.TestId = __document_id
```

Comment: Since I found this post via google, you _do_ need this.__document_id.

Comment: @KijanaWoodard not when I just tried it in build 2879.

Comment: i second that - in build 2879, this.__document_id DOES NOT work, simply __document_id does.

Comment: This answer is indeed correct. I just tested in 3.0, and __document_id works, while this.__document_id does not.